# What options are there for doing spell-checking in emacs

Tags: spell-checking, writing

Because I'm currently doing a lot of non-programming tasks in Emacs, spell-checking became one of my major concerns once again.

I noticed that there is no question related to the options for spell-checking in Emacs yet, so here we go:

> What are my options to do spell-checking in Emacs?

Specifically,

- for general purpose spell-checking, i.e. sensible suggestions for typos, spell correction of words
- for selective spell-checking, e.g. general purpose spell-check but **only** in comments
- for anything which I forgot or am not aware of but you can think of (spell-check related, duh...)

<sub>**Edit:** Forked off the *"other"* stuff in a separate question, [What options are there for writing better texts in emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/what-options-are-there-for-writing-better-texts-in-emacs)</sub>

Comment: I recommend  this page: [Spelling in Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Spelling.html)

Comment: As it stands this question is [too broad](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I suggest to restrict it to the second bullet point (selecting spell-checking), and maybe ask about grammar separately.

Comment: Only your first two items are about spell checking. Grammar and language are not spell checking, and your last three items would make an entirely different question altogether.

Comment: Although I don't really agree that the original question was too broad or composed of two vastly different questions, I have forked the second part. This question is now **only** about spell-checking, the other one about grammar checking and writing better texts.

Answer (score 10):

- For general purpose spell-checking, there are quite a few popular alternatives

  1. `ispell` and friends: Built into emacs & typically called with `ispell-buffer`. Checks spelling only on demand.
  2. `flyspell-mode`: Also built-in and provides on-the-fly spell checking and highlights mistakes.
  3. `speck-mode`: Available from MELPA, it checks the spelling of the word once you pause after typing. Also has a few distinguishing features from flyspell mode like able to use multiple dictionaries in the same buffer. (Disclaimer : I only used this mode briefly a long time back)

Note that all the above require dedicated spell-checking programs such as `aspell` or `hunspell` and appropriate dictionaries. The modes only provide a convenient emacs interface to the command line programs.

- For selective spell checking, you can customize `flyspell-mode` with the variable `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` by wiring a function that selects which words must be checked. Your listed example is easy though -- Just use `flyspell-prog-mode` which only checks comments in code buffers.

Comment: First, let me thank you for your answer. Following the comments by Gilles and Malabarba I have forked the question into two parts. Therefore, I'd suggest that you post the second part of your answer (the one about `weasel-word`) as an answer to the new question. You can find the link in my original question.

Comment: Please add [`wcheck`](https://github.com/tlikonen/wcheck-mode) to your list.  It's very good, though `flyspell` has become so good lately, that I don't use `wcheck` anymore.

Comment: For OSX, the highly customized version of Emacs called Aquamacs has built-in support for the native OSX spellchecker (including, the accompanying OSX user dictionary of words that have been added by the user).  That is a specialty item that no other Emacs version can offer.

Answer (score 6):

@Vamsi's answer already covers general-purpose and selective spell-checking. But what about **personalized auto-correction**? @Malabarba has a [nice post](http://endlessparentheses.com/ispell-and-abbrev-the-perfect-auto-correct.html) about this topic on his [blog](http://endlessparentheses.com/). The basic idea is to store pairs of misspelled words and appropriate corrections as [Abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html). Here is (a slightly modified version of) the code that lets you do this easily:

```el
(defun ispell-word-then-abbrev (p)
  "Call `ispell-word'. Then create an abbrev for the correction made.
With prefix P, create local abbrev. Otherwise it will be global."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((before (downcase (or (thing-at-point 'word) "")))
        after)
    (call-interactively 'ispell-word)
    (setq after (downcase (or (thing-at-point 'word) "")))
    (unless (string= after before)
      (define-abbrev
        (if p local-abbrev-table global-abbrev-table) before after))
      (message "\"%s\" now expands to \"%s\" %sally."
               before after (if p "loc" "glob"))))

(define-key ctl-x-map (kbd "C-i") 'ispell-word-then-abbrev)
(setq save-abbrevs t)
(setq-default abbrev-mode t)
```

With this in place, you can simply

1. hit <kbd>C-x C-i</kbd> after a misspelled word
2. select a correction, and
3. *never worry about it again*

because from now on Emacs will automatically replace the misspelled version of the word with the correction. It's hard to put into words just how useful this is!

---

If you want to supercharge Emacs' new-found auto-correction capabilities, you can add the abbrevs defined [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/autocorrection_abbrev_defs) to your `abbrev_defs` file.