# What options are there for writing better non-programming text in Emacs?

Tags: text-editing, text, writing

This is a fork from the question [What options are there for doing spell-checking in Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/what-options-are-there-for-doing-spell-checking-in-emacs)

Because I'm currently doing a lot of non-programming tasks in Emacs I'm wondering whether Emacs can support me in writing *better* texts.

So, let's open with the obligatory question phrase

> Are there any packages/libraries/built-ins tailored to help me write better, more correct and concise texts in Emacs?

Specifically,

- for **grammar spell check**. Something similar to (but hopefully better than) the MS Word spell-checker which recognizes if a sentence is grammatically wrong
- for improving your phrasing and the expressions you are using. Something along the lines of [*Dead Poets Society*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097165):

  > So avoid using the word 'very' because it's lazy. A man is not very tired, he is exhausted. Don't use very sad, use morose. [...]
- for anything which **I** forgot or am not aware of but you can think of (phrasing/language improvement-related, duh...)

Comment: “Anything which I forgot” is intrinsically too broad. “Improving your phrasing” is awfully vague, too.

Comment: Hence I have restricted the "anything" with that part in parentheses... Also, I don't see in what possible way "improving your phrasing" could be vague inn the context of writing.

Comment: Improving your phrasing etc. is off-topic here, I should think.  There are SE sites for learning to write better.  Your question should be confined to **how Emacs can help** you write and edit text.  And that is already very broad - it could be considered too broad for a single question. Can you imagine if all of the questions about writing-help are bundled into just your one question? You would be much better off focusing on one thing at a time. And everyone else would benefit from that also.

Comment: Trad Unix had `style` and `diction`, and I am vaguely aware of an attempt to [reimplement them as open source](https://www.gnu.org/software/diction/).  If the tools actually work, adding an Emacs wrapper should be a snap.

Comment: Computers cannot effectively improve your writing, at least currently. Geoffrey K. Pullum and Mark Liberman write about this a lot, for example, see http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/myl/languagelog/archives/005061.html or http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=10416

As an example of how silly this is, I installed `writegood-mode` and yanked in the first paragraph of "My Old Man" (from the above link). `writegood-mode` identifies "my old man was cut out for a fat guy" as passive, which it is not.

These systems a) do not work well and b) are based on bad rules about good writing.

Answer (score 67):

I personally stick to writing things in `org-mode` with `flyspell-mode` and `langtool`...

`org-mode` is fantastic for typing any sort of document quickly in Emacs, flyspell takes care of spelling, and langtool worries about the grammar. Everything is highly customizable too, so you can customize anything to your heart's content.

Here is a quick little type-up in org-mode with langtool and flyspell enabled; nothing too special.

[image]

If I run `langtool-correct-buffer` like it suggests, any grammar errors langtool found are highlighted one by one with a number of suggestions in the bottom buffer. I can select any of these candidates with the corresponding number key, or just skip over them with the [Space bar].

[image]

In addition flyspell lets me [Middle Click] on misspelled words to see spelling suggestions.

[image]

`org-mode` has a *ton* of export formats; you can export your document as a PDF, ODT, or even as HTML. (You can export using `C-c C-e` in `org-mode`)

[image]

Now that I've published my masterpiece as a PDF using LaTeX, this is what I see when I open it in a PDF viewer...

[image]

It is probably the easiest way to make fancy-looking documents within a relatively good writing environment in Emacs...

The good news is that `org-mode` and `flyspell-mode` are included by default with most versions of Emacs. The bad news is that langtool is not, and it is somewhat large, and it requires Java... But if that doesn't deter you:

[Langtool](https://www.languagetool.org/) is a grammar checker that is commonly paired with Openoffice or Libreoffice. The tool itself is a simple command line utility, so it is relatively easy to interface with other programs; someone interfaced it with Emacs.

To add it in Emacs, you can install it with `M-x package-install langtool`...Or, if you don't have the right repos set up (I use the ones suggested [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA#toc1).), you can get the `.el` file and include it manually from [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/langtool.el).

I currently have my org-mode hook set up like this. (Snipping the irrelevant bits.)

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
   (progn
     ;; Snipped
     (auto-fill-mode t)

     ;; Spelling
     (flyspell-mode t)

     ;; Grammar
     (require 'langtool)
     (setq langtool-language-tool-jar "/path/to/LanguageTool.jar"))))
```

Obviously, you would want to replace the `/path/to/LanguageTool.jar` with the actual path to it on your system. It is a portable .jar file, so the location doesn't really matter.

Also, unlike `flyspell-mode`, langtool requires you to run `M-x langtool-check` when you want to grammar check the buffer... So you don't have fancy grammar checking as you type currently.

`org-mode` can do a ton, and can be used to write simple little notes files, complete essays with fancy graphics, articles, books, you name it... But since it can do so much, it's kind of hard to know where to start. I found it was easiest to learn by starting with [the possible ways you can export an `org-mode` file](http://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting.html) after you [learn the basics...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJTwQvgfgMM). [Org-mode's site](http://orgmode.org/) is very helpful and informative, and there is a lot of help on it in the info pages too (`C-h i`, `m Org Mode`).

Good luck..! And hope this helps.

Comment: This is **great**! `langtool` looks very promising indeed.

Comment: Is there a way to configure `langtool` to be aware of `(La)TeX` syntax? I'd say about half of the errors are false positives caused by `(La)TeX`'s syntax which is a bit annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately, not to my knowledge. I usually write my stuff in plain org with very little LaTeX except for inside org LaTeX directives. (Like `#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [hidelinks,11pt]`) That way I have nothing that `langtool` would pick up. That's not to say a way to change where langtool doesn't exist of course, but simply that it is beyond my particular knowledge on the subject. Sorry..!

Comment: Are you still using ``langtool`` with Emacs? I follow the instructions, but when I ``M-x langtool-check`` Emacs opens the stand-alone ``langtool`` and since then nothing is available in Emacs, till I cancel it. Are you aware of an up-to-date instruction for setting it up?

Comment: Can `langtool` ignore the suggestion in the emacs's buffer and save it in order to clear the colorized text for the next emac session?

Answer (score 16):

The EmacsWiki category [***Writing***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWriting) is the place to start.

It lists dozens of libraries that support writing text using Emacs, with one-liner descriptions and links to the detail pages.

There is no sense listing such info again here - consult it there.

(But perhaps others here will have specific recommendations.)

I will mention only the subcategory page [Thesauri and Synonyms](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThesauriAndSynonyms), which has more links to information about libraries that support synonym lookup.

Comment: Those recommendations and the personal experience with different options are what I'm mostly interested in :-)

Comment: Fine.  You should also find plenty of that on the wiki pages for this topic.

Comment: @Drew: langtool is missing on the emacswiki page.

Comment: @tobias: Yes, please add langtool to the list on the wiki (anyone can edit the wiki - it's a wiki ;-)).

Comment: Done. BTW: Could you have a look at [some (IMHO interesting) dired+ question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51727/copy-all-dirs-exclude-all-subdirs-with-name-build/51748#comment79827_51748). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

I write novels using Emacs, and have developed a workflow over time based on certain unique advantages of it. (Example: [My most recent book](https://www.hmhco.com/shop/books/The-Trap/9780547824086) was conceived, composed, and edited with Emacs.) That said, it is not a road without difficulties.

- Org-mode

  Org-mode is the reason I began using Emacs. Being able to fold and
  unfold sections of a ~50K-words manuscript is invaluable. I
  previously used the program [Scrivener](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php) but became disenchanted
  with its bloat and unplain-text `.scriv` files. Org-mode also has
  the ability to move chapters (`trees` and `subtrees`) around easily
  (with `M-arrow_key`).
- Text Manipulation

  In addition to emacs' plethora of text-finding, slicing, and pasting
  utilities (`C-s`, `M-y`, etc. etc.) I use [god mode](https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode) and
  [avy mode](https://github.com/abo-abo/avy) to find my way around a buffer. The modal editing
  enabled by the former helps with my arthritis. The latter is an
  extremely fast way of navigating onscreen with just a few
  keystrokes (usually on the home row).
- Flyspell

  This is a perfectly adequate spell checker that benefits me every
  day.
- Magit

  I recently began using [Git](https://git-scm.com/) via [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) to manage my work with
  version control. I'm a beginner, but there are tremendous advantages,
  and [Magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) is an excellent interface to that system. Though `Git`
  isn't exactly optimized for novel writing, it works well enough.
- TODO and COMMENT

  Org-mode has the ability to define jobs to do. With a large MS there
  might be 40 or more things I need to remember, from small to large.
  These can be identified and even ranked with [TODO keywords](http://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-Items.html#TODO-Items).
  Also, various notes and ideas headlines can be prefaced with
  `COMMENT`, which won't export when I send the file to `.odt`.
- Split window

  I often work on a file with a split window, showing two locations in
  a story. I frequently compare one location with another. For a long
  while I did this with `split-window-right` (`C-x 3`), but I've
  recently switched to `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window` (`C-x 4
  c`). The advantage here is that if I change the folding state of
  window A, it does not change the folding state of window B.
- One Disadvantage

  Literary publishing runs on MSWord. It is *possible* to get from
  `.org` to `.doc` but not, for me, easy. I presently use Emacs'
  `org-export` to port files to `.odt`, which I edit with
  [Libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/). I manually, or with macros, achieve the formatting
  necessary for the larger publishing world as I know it, then save the
  file to `.doc` The formatting is not complex, but it is required.

  The editorial process involves considerable back and forth, which means
  that I serially export to Libreoffice and re-import to Emacs. On the
  Emacs end, macros can retrieve the asterisks for my
  headlines and straighten Word's smartquotes. I presently have no good
  solution for italics. Sometimes I introduce errors. If Emacs wasn't
  such an amazing text editing environment, I wouldn't suffer through
  this.

  Mickey Petersen has an excellent blog post describing [his own
  workflow](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/how-to-write-a-book-in-emacs) for his book *Mastering Emacs,* which makes
  use of `diff` buffers to sort changes and comments (beyond my ken at
  present), and also requires his literary editor/publisher to look at
  plain-text files (which I've gotten pushback on, when I've tried it).
- Conclusion

  Emacs is the most effective tool I've found for writing and editing novels. There are also many
  modes that might be of use to writers of other kinds of prose (such as
  [org2blog](https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog) for composing and posting Wordpress blogs and
  [AUCTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) for writing LaTeX files).

  I'd love to see a future where the link between `.txt` and `.doc` was
  smoother for the kind of writing I do. This would include:

  - setting Emacs to use double spacing or single spacing when requested
  - inserting manual page breaks (for instance, after a title page)
  - italics that don't fail around some punctuation marks
  - creating simple, right-justified headers on all pages but the title

  There are workarounds ([here](http://thewanderingcoder.com/2015/03/emacs-org-mode-styling-non-smart-quotes-zero-width-space-and-tex-input-method/) is a blog post by Sean Miller about
  getting Emacs to consistently show italics that include punctuation, which encourages use of a zero-width space), and certainly things I don't yet know how to do as someone coming from the literary rather than the programming side of the text-editing world.

Awhile ago I chanced upon a newsgroup post by rms titled "Emacs as word processor":

> 25 years ago I hoped we would extend Emacs to do WYSIWG word
>   processing.  That is why we added text properties and variable width
>   fonts.  However, more features are still needed to achieve this.
>
> Could people please start working on the features that are needed?

I'd love to see a future where I could do all of my literary work in Emacs without ever having to launch another editor. I'm not there now, but nonetheless am happy overall, because the amazing utility of this editor is more than worth the extra work on the export end.

Comment: maybe undoc would help you? doc importer for emacs http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnDoc

Comment: I'll have a look. I've used antiword before, and it was more work than it was worth, because of formatting changes that occur during extraction. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 11):

Spin off of the original answer to the [linked question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/what-options-are-there-for-doing-spell-checking-in-emacs).

- Grammar Check: I am not aware of any dedicated grammar parsers for emacs yet. I will mention `writegood-mode` available in MELPA which highlights [weasel words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word) and passive voice in the buffer. It gets you half the way there.

  Another possibly useful library is [`dupwords.el`](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/sje30/emacs/dupwords.el) which can highlight if a particular word (typically nouns and pronouns) are used more than once in the same sentence. This is more general than finding repeated adjacent words which can be handled by flyspell.
- Anything else: Correcting language in general is a hard problem. That being said, if there exists any external program/script in this area, it is usually easy to make it interface with emacs.

If you use *LaTeX* for writing, I have personally found the following ruby scripts quite useful for checking style and consistency. I just call the shell command from the minibuffer itself. A viewer capable of forward and inverse search is also valuable when proofreading. On MS Windows, I use `sumatra-forward` package from ELPA for forward search in SumatraPDF viewer.

1. [style-check by Neil Spring](http://cs.umd.edu/%7Enspring/software/)
2. [hyphen-consistency by Neil Conway](https://github.com/neilconway/paper-scripts)

Answer (score 2):

This tip will allow you to **format words / regions** (bold, italics, strike through, but also parens, quotes, etc) **with a single keystroke**, instead of adding '`/`', '`*`', etc. at the beginning and at the end of your text. I find this useful when writing, as when re-reading and fine-tuning written texts :

```
(defun xa-bold (&optional char)
  (interactive)
  (unless (region-active-p)
    (backward-word)
    (mark-word))
  (if (region-active-p)
      (insert-pair 1 ?* ?*)
    (insert "//")
    (backward-char))
  (forward-word)
  (right-char))
```

This code is for getting a bold word/region. All you have to do is to replace the first and second ’`*`’ in `(insert-pair 1 ?* ?*)`according to what type of formatting you want. For parens, go with  `(insert-pair 1 ?\( ?\))`

Just bind a key to it and you're done :

```
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-&") 'xa-bold)
```

Note : I felt free to add a minor change to the code I’ve stolen here. I added `(forward-word) (right-char)` at the end of the function because when you’re writing and want to format a word, you want `point` to go **after** the formatting character, so you can go on writing after. But you might want remove `(right-char)` for parens or quotes, to stay **inside** the paren or quote and go on writing.

I'm not a programmer, just an emacs enthousiast, playing at times with existent code. And I want emacs to become my word processor!