# Hi-lighting common grammar mistakes in all prose across modes with English text

Tags: text-editing, text

I already make extensive use of *flyspell-mode* to keep my errant spelling in check. However I'm currently trying to break the bad habit of using "it's" for possessive statements. I've had a brief look around and haven't found any grammar checkers but really all I need is to visually hi-light common errors in any buffer which can accept textual prose. Any suggestions of the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Closely related: [What options are there for writing better texts in Emacs?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2171/504)

Answer (score 2):

A brief Google search ("open source English grammar checker" and "langtool emacs") led me to [`langtool.el`](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-langtool), which can be installed using [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/langtool).

PS: I haven't tried it yet, but I definitely will.

Comment: Seems like that needs an external java library. I'm not sure if it's commonly packaged. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

My very low rent solution for this particular problem was to use hi-lock mode:

```
(defun my-hightlight-non-possessive-its ()
  "Turn on hi-lock mode for any (potentially incorrect) usage of it's"
  (interactive)
  (hi-lock-face-phrase-buffer "it's"))

;; Hooks for non-possessive its
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-hightlight-non-possessive-its)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-hightlight-non-possessive-its))
```