# Org-mode highlighting or font coloring

Tags: org-mode, highlighting

I'm using org-mode for writing and want to be able to highlight sentences or paragraphs which need to be re-written or fact-checked so that those bits are obvious looking through the document.  Is there a way to do this?  I thought about trying to do it using inline comments but I can't figure out a way to do it so that they show up in color and I couldn't get hi-lock to work with highlighting a long sentence as opposed to a reg-ex like you'd use for code.  Alternatively, if anyone has another way of making that kind of text easy to find other than coloring then I would be happy to try it.  Sorry if this has already been asked but I've had a look and can't find it anywhere.

Edited to add:
I'm currently using spacemacs - not sure if that makes a difference - but would be willing to try another flavour of emacs if necessary to get this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5892/19232) post, looks like it should handle your requirements.

Another option, that however would be a little more work, is to wrap any sentences like below:

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
  Paragraph goes here
#+END_QUOTE
```

Answer (score 2):

You also might be interested in the tip I gave there : https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41834/17078

... which tells you how to **format words / regions** (bold, italics, strike through, but also parens, quotes, etc) **with a single keystroke**...

Answer (score 1):

How are you recognizing the sentences or paragraphs that you want to highlight? Are you deciding on your own, or are you expecting such recognition to be programmatic?

I'm guessing that you are deciding/choosing which text to highlight based on your own considerations and you do not expect Emacs to do so (e.g. based on rules, patterns, or conditions).

If so, you can use library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)) to highlight any arbitrary text.  You can highlight the region or highlight by dragging the mouse like a marker pen.