# Copy all dirs exclude all subdirs with name "build"

Tags: dired

emacs 26.1

dired+

I have dir `my_dir`. This dir contains 10 subdirs. In every of those dirs there are 2 subdirs:

- `src`
- `build`

I need to copy in DIRED MODE all dirs and files from `my_dir` to `my_dir2` and **exclude** all subdirs with name `build`.

Is it possible?

P.S. subdirs **build** content thousands files. So copy without this folders is much faster.

P.P.S.
Here approach how I can do this in Total Commander.

I use file types like this:

```
*.* | build\
```

[image]

As result while copying , then copy all dirs **exclude** all subdirs **build**. It's very simple and comfortably.

Is it possible this approach same on Emacs ?

Answer (score 1):

First a method that works with vanilla `dired+`:

1. Go to `my_dir`.
2. Mark all by placing point on the first line and pressing <kbd>m</kbd> in the dired buffer.
3. Copy the marked files to the destination `my_dir2` with <kbd>C</kbd> and giving the right target directory.
4. Go to `my_dir2`.
5. Filter the unwanted directories by <kbd>C-x d</kbd> with filter `*/build`.
6. Mark all shown directories and delete them with <kbd>C-x h</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>.

### Comment

The clear disadvantage of this method is that copy the unwanted directories and delete them afterwards. That can be really bad if those directories are big and you are working on SSD drives.

The problem with selecting all `*/src` directories in `my_dir` and copying them is that the source file names are stripped off their path in `dired-do-create-files` by `file-name-nondirectory`. If `0`, ..., `9` are the sub-directories of `my_dir` then `src` of `0/src`, `src` of `1/src` ... all end up as `my_dir2/src`.

Comment: I need exclude subdirs "build" while copy dir. Because without many subdirs "build" the copy of dir "my_dir" is much faster.

Comment: @Alex In that case you should take the [alternative approach](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51748/2370). Just copy the Elisp stuff to your init file, reload Emacs, and go through the steps given below the code afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The second method I propose bases on tweaking dired(+) such that copying of relative paths like `0/src`, ..., `9/src` from `my_dir` to `my_dir2` becomes possible.

The main problem with vanilla dired+ is already [described in my other answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51747/2370).

The following Elisp source code optionally replaces `file-name-nondirectory` with `file-relative-name` in `dired-do-create-files`. One can switch back to the original behavior  by setting the customization option `dired-copy-relative-src` to nil.
One also needs to give `copy-directory` in `dired-copy-file-recursive` a non-nil `PARENT` argument to accept the relative paths passed from `dired-do-create-files`.

```el
(defcustom dired-copy-relative-src t
  "Use the relative source file name as target for copying."
  :group 'dired
  :type 'boolean)

(require 'dired-aux)

(defun dired-do-create-files (op-symbol file-creator operation arg
                    &optional marker-char op1
                    how-to)
  "Create a new file for each marked file.
Prompt user for a target directory in which to create the new
  files.  The target may also be a non-directory file, if only
  one file is marked.  The initial suggestion for target is the
  Dired buffer's current directory (or, if `dired-dwim-target' is
  non-nil, the current directory of a neighboring Dired window).
OP-SYMBOL is the symbol for the operation.  Function `dired-mark-pop-up'
  will determine whether pop-ups are appropriate for this OP-SYMBOL.
FILE-CREATOR and OPERATION as in `dired-create-files'.
ARG as in `dired-get-marked-files'.
Optional arg MARKER-CHAR as in `dired-create-files'.
Optional arg OP1 is an alternate form for OPERATION if there is
  only one file.
Optional arg HOW-TO determines how to treat the target.
  If HOW-TO is nil, use `file-directory-p' to determine if the
   target is a directory.  If so, the marked file(s) are created
   inside that directory.  Otherwise, the target is a plain file;
   an error is raised unless there is exactly one marked file.
  If HOW-TO is t, target is always treated as a plain file.
  Otherwise, HOW-TO should be a function of one argument, TARGET.
   If its return value is nil, TARGET is regarded as a plain file.
   If it return value is a list, TARGET is a generalized
    directory (e.g. some sort of archive).  The first element of
    this list must be a function with at least four arguments:
      operation - as OPERATION above.
      rfn-list  - list of the relative names for the marked files.
      fn-list   - list of the absolute names for the marked files.
      target    - the name of the target itself.
    The rest of elements of the list returned by HOW-TO are optional
    arguments for the function that is the first element of the list.
   For any other return value, TARGET is treated as a directory."
  (or op1 (setq op1 operation))
  (let* ((fn-list (dired-get-marked-files nil arg))
     (rfn-list (mapcar #'dired-make-relative fn-list))
     (dired-one-file    ; fluid variable inside dired-create-files
      (and (consp fn-list) (null (cdr fn-list)) (car fn-list)))
     (target-dir (dired-dwim-target-directory))
     (default (and dired-one-file
               (not dired-dwim-target) ; Bug#25609
               (expand-file-name (file-name-nondirectory (car fn-list))
                     target-dir)))
     (defaults (dired-dwim-target-defaults fn-list target-dir))
     (target (expand-file-name ; fluid variable inside dired-create-files
          (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
              (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'minibuffer-default-add-function) nil)
            (setq minibuffer-default defaults))
            (dired-mark-read-file-name
             (concat (if dired-one-file op1 operation) " %s to: ")
             target-dir op-symbol arg rfn-list default))))
     (into-dir (cond ((null how-to)
              ;; Allow users to change the letter case of
              ;; a directory on a case-insensitive
              ;; filesystem.  If we don't test these
              ;; conditions up front, file-directory-p
              ;; below will return t on a case-insensitive
              ;; filesystem, and Emacs will try to move
              ;; foo -> foo/foo, which fails.
              (if (and (file-name-case-insensitive-p (car fn-list))
                   (eq op-symbol 'move)
                   dired-one-file
                   (string= (downcase
                         (expand-file-name (car fn-list)))
                        (downcase
                         (expand-file-name target)))
                   (not (string=
                     (file-name-nondirectory (car fn-list))
                     (file-name-nondirectory target))))
                  nil
                (file-directory-p target)))
             ((eq how-to t) nil)
             (t (funcall how-to target)))))
    (if (and (consp into-dir) (functionp (car into-dir)))
    (apply (car into-dir) operation rfn-list fn-list target (cdr into-dir))
      (if (not (or dired-one-file into-dir))
      (error "Marked %s: target must be a directory: %s" operation target))
      ;; rename-file bombs when moving directories unless we do this:
      (or into-dir (setq target (directory-file-name target)))
      (dired-create-files
       file-creator operation fn-list
       (if into-dir         ; target is a directory
       ;; This function uses fluid variable target when called
       ;; inside dired-create-files:
       `(lambda (from)
          (expand-file-name ,(if dired-copy-relative-src
                     `(file-relative-name from ,default-directory) ;; CHANGE: Use `file-relative-name' instead of `file-name-nondirectory'
                   '(file-name-nondirectory from))
                target))
     (lambda (_from) target))
       marker-char))))

(defun dired-copy-file-recursive (from to ok-flag &optional
                       preserve-time top recursive)
  (when (and (eq t (car (file-attributes from)))
         (file-in-directory-p to from))
    (error "Cannot copy `%s' into its subdirectory `%s'" from to))
  (let ((attrs (file-attributes from)))
    (if (and recursive
         (eq t (car attrs))
         (or (eq recursive 'always)
         (yes-or-no-p (format "Recursive copies of %s? " from))))
    (copy-directory from to preserve-time 'parents) ;; CHANGE: added 'parents
      (or top (dired-handle-overwrite to))
      (condition-case err
      (if (stringp (car attrs))
          ;; It is a symlink
          (make-symbolic-link (car attrs) to ok-flag)
        (copy-file from to ok-flag preserve-time))
    (file-date-error
     (push (dired-make-relative from)
           dired-create-files-failures)
     (dired-log "Can't set date on %s:\n%s\n" from err))))))
```

If you have installed the above Elisp code you can copy what you want as follows:

1. Go to `my_dir`
2. Copy all regular files by the following steps:

   1. Mark all by <kbd>C-x h</kbd> <kbd>*m</kbd>
   2. Unmark directories with <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>*/</kbd>
   3. Copy the marked files with <kbd>C</kbd> into `my_dir2`
3. Copy the directories without `*/build` from `my_dir` to `my_dir2` as follows:

   1. Filter files in sub-directories by <kbd>C-x d</kbd> `*/*`
   2. Mark all by <kbd>C-x h</kbd> <kbd>*m</kbd>
   3. Unmark unwanted directories by <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>%m</kbd> `/build`
   4. Copy the marked stuff by <kbd>C</kbd>

Test conditions:

- `emacs-version`: `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-04-12`
- started with `emacs -Q` and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-initialize`
- `dired+`.Version: 21.2 but `dired-copy-file-recursive` and `dired-do-create-files` are from vanilla dired

Comment: @Drew Hi Drew,  Does dired+ already have the possibility to copy the source recursive (inclusively the directory structure) and thereby leaving out some subfolders? Is something like I describe possible? I.e., listing the files and directories with their relative paths w.r.t. `default-directory`, marking some files there and copying the marked stuff inclusively their relative paths into another base-directory?

Comment: (Replied to the same question in your email, this morning.) No, it doesn't currently. Would maybe be good to add an optional `PREDICATE` arg to some more of the Dired functions.

Comment: @Tobias I updated my post. Is it possible same approach on Emacs?